# C# Windows Form DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, label, model-binding

I have found databinding in WinForm:

```
       BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
       test t = new test ();
       t.Foo = "Ahmet";
       bs.DataSource = t;
       label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Foo", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

That works but I need more complex data binding. 
I have Area,Desk classes. I get datas from db and create List object. All areas have many desks.

I tried following but it doesn't work.Button Text is null. How can I use data binding ?

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

foreach (Area area in areaList)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.AutoSize = false;
                btn.Width = 100;
                btn.BringToFront();
                btn.Height = 35;
                btn.Font= new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
                btn.BackColor = Color.White;
                btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                btn.Margin = new Padding(3,5,3,5);
                btn.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs,"Name",false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnAreaClick);

                fpnlAreas.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
```

Area Class

```
public class Area : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _id;
        private string _name;
        private List<Table> _table;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public List<Table> ListOfTable
        {
            get { return _table; }
            set { _table = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListOfTable");
            }
        }




        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }


        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public Area()
        {
            ListOfTable = new List<Entity.Table>();
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
            }
        }

    }
```

Desk Class

```
public class Table
    {
        private string _id;
        private string _name;


        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public Table()
        {
            ListOfBill = new List<Bill>();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding doesn't work because you didn't set the Datasource of the BindingSource.

Adapt your code to create a BindingSource for each Area and use that one, like so:

```
foreach (Area area in areaList)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = area;

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.AutoSize = false;
    btn.Width = 100;
    btn.BringToFront();
    btn.Height = 35;
    btn.Font= new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
    btn.BackColor = Color.White;
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    btn.Margin = new Padding(3,5,3,5);
    btn.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs,"Name",false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnAreaClick);

    fpnlAreas.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```